# New line right aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment

What I'm trying to do is right-align a new line. In other words, I want to have a block of justified text, as normal, and then I wish to have a line break, with the new line right-aligned like this:

```
|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,|
|sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore ma-|
|gna aliqua.                                             |
|                                                    Text|
```

If the pipes indicate the margins (hyphenation may not respect Latin hyphenation rules, this is just a quick and dirty demonstration).

I tried using the `flushright` environment, but this, of course, starts a new paragraph, which I do not want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{flushright}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried to use the `\raggedleft` declaration, but if I try scoping it:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \\
{\raggedleft Text}
```

It does not right-align `Text` at all.

I also tried using the `\hfill` command. This does not seem to work at the beginning of a new line, but I was able to quick-and-dirty my way around that problem. Nevertheless, `\hfill` doesn't quite fill the whole line, for some reason, leaving me with far-from right-aligned `Text`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \\
\hspace*{0pt}\hfill Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Possible complications

Firstly, I would, ideally, like to be able to use any solution within an `enumerate` environment.

Secondly, I was initially trying to define a command for a logical structure. I began with:

```
\newcommand{\grade}[1]{\newline\textbf{Grade} #1}
```

And then thought it would look better if I could right-align the grade. As such, ideally, I would like a solution that can be incorporated into the definition of a new command.

Comment: The `\hfill` approach seems to work for me if you add \\ after `Text`.

Comment: You would need `{\raggedleft Text\par}`...

Comment: @Werner that seems, bizarrely, to have centred the text above (modifying my `\raggedleft` example above by adding `\par` as you describe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue `\par\nopagebreak` under zero `\parskip`, which is obtained by using a group, so the value of `\parskip` will be restored at `\endgroup`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\lastline}[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\par\nopagebreak
  \raggedleft#1\par\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\lastline{Some text that's flush right.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\lastline{Some text that's flush right.}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order for `\raggedleft` (or any other paragraph-related adjusment) to have effect, you need to insert a "paragraph marker". This could be as simple as leaving a blank line, or issuing a verbatim `\par`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\grade}[1]{%
  \par
  \vspace*{-\parskip}% Correct insertion of paragraph skip due to \par
  {\raggedleft\textbf{Grade} #1\par}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \\
\hspace*{0pt}\hfill Text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\grade{Text}

\end{document}
```

Using `\\` doesn't insert a paragraph gap. However, in order to make use of `\raggedleft` one needs a `\par`. Since `\grade` issues `\par`, a vertical correction of `\parskip` restores any unwanted gap that is inserted between paragraphs.